# Reducing the number of computations in matrix comparison

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I'm writing an algorithm to compute distance between elements. For example I have a data set with 3 rows and 2 columns, (students A, B and C) and their heights respectively. I have to take the difference in distance for all elements and compute a matrix. All the possible computations are A-A, A-B, A-C, B-A, B-B, B-C, C-A, C-B, C-C. But the absolute difference in A-B and B-A are equal.

At the moment I have used an if condition to avoid comparing similar elements (A-A, B-B). But still there are repeated computations. My goal is to avoid the repeated computations.

For example if A-B is done then B-A will not be computed and value of A-B will be assigned to the correct matrix position. It would helpful if someone could advise me on this.

**Update**: 
Scenario: I have 3 [files](http://1drv.ms/1N776wH) (data_A, data_B and data_C). Consider these files as models. Each model has a set of attributes (A, B, C, D). Different models have different attributes. For example data_A (A,B,C), data_B has (A,D,C) and data_C has (A,B,C).

My goal is to compare the models based on their common attributes. First of all I scan the models and find out what attributes are common to all the models. In this case it’s only A and C. Next I would do a pair-wise comparison on each model based on the common attributes. For example I would calculate the Euclidean distance for A in data_A and A in data_B, C in data_A and C in data_B. First I would compute the sum of the squared differences for each pair and then calculate the square root of that value. This is repeated for all the metabolite pairs in each model pair and finally a cumulative value of the square-root distances would give me a single distance value between the models.

My issue is in my algorithm if I compare data_A with data_B I don’t have to do the reverse computation (i.e data_B with data_A). At the moment I’m ignoring only the comparison of the same data set using an if condition. Below is my code. It might not be the most optimal way to write it.

```
setwd("E:/Assignment")
uniqueDataSets = list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
commonVariables = c("A","C")

#To store the distances
results  = data.frame(DataSet1 = character(), DataSet2 = character(), Distance=numeric() , stringsAsFactors = F)

for(i in 1:length(uniqueDataSets)) #loading the files as reference file
{
  currentDataSetName = uniqueDataSets[i]
  currentDataSet = read.csv(currentDataSetName)

  for(j in 1:length(uniqueDataSets)) #loading the file as comparison files
  {
    comparedDataSetName = uniqueDataSets[j]
    comparedDataSet = read.csv(comparedDataSetName)

    totalDistance = 0
    tempDist = 0

    if(currentDataSetName != comparedDataSetName) #Ignoring comparison if it's the same data set
    {
      for(k in 1:length(commonVariables)) #computing pair wise distance for each metabolite
      {
        var1 = currentDataSet[commonVariables[k]]
        var2 = comparedDataSet[commonVariables[k]]

        tempDist = sqrt(sum((var1 - var2)^2))
        totalDistance = totalDistance + tempDist #cumulative value of the distance between 2 models
      }

    } else{
      totalDistance = 0
    }

    results = rbind(results, data.frame(DataSet1=currentDataSetName, DataSet2 = comparedDataSetName, Distance =totalDistance))

  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you want `?dist`

Comment: Combinations are returned by the `combn` function. Distance "matrices" are not really R matrices but @jeremycg seems to have nailed your request.

Comment: @BoundedDust I think you are right. I'm not sure whether it's right to specify this as a R question. I'm looking for a generic answer. But I'll be programming in R.

Answer (score 2):

R has this built in:

```
x <- matrix(c(1.56, 1.64, 1.75), nrow = 3)
row.names(x) <-c("a", "b", "c")
dist(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here the distance computation is my own function. In that case how should I specify this? In the dist() API it supports only predefined distance measures.

Comment: it depends on what your function inputs and outputs - maybe put that and some sample data in your question for more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways using @jeremycg's data:

```
utils::combn(x, m=2, FUN=diff)
combn(x, m=2, FUN=`-`)
```

Admittedly, these are a little slower for large datasets. They both give:

```
[1] 0.08 0.19 0.11
```